# Proving the existence and uniqueness of a cyclic group of $G$ (Group Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. For every divisor $d$ of $n$, prove that $G$  has exactly one subgroup of order $d$

What i tried

I know i have to prove the existence and uniqueness here

For the portion on existence

Since $G$ is a cyclic group, the $G$ is written in the form $G=<g>$ Where $g$ is the generator of the group $G$

I then let $g^{k}$ be the subgroup of order $d$ and i thus have to prove its existence, ie prove the following statement

$$o(g^k)=d$$

Also another info that i have is that $d$ is the divisor of $n$ thus

$$d|n$$ which implies $$n=kd$$

next i make use of the formula

$$o(g^k)=\frac{n}{gcd(n,k)}$$

in order to get what i want to prove

Next

given that $n=kd$ implies $k=\frac{n}{d}$

subsituting into  $gcd(n,k)=$

i  got

$$gcd(n,k)=gcd(n,\frac{n}{d})=\frac{n}{d}$$

Which thus implies that 
$$o(g^k)=\frac{n}{gcd(n,k)}=\frac{n}{gcd(n,\frac{n}{d})}=\frac{n}{\frac{n}{d}}=d$$
which thus prove the statement that $o(g^k)=d$
Is my proof correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: I meant to insert [THIS QUESTION](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142819/uniqueness-of-subgroups-of-a-given-order-in-a-cyclic-group) as the question to which this question here is a duplicate.

Comment: That feedback helps us understand the specific question of your post, which involves <proof verification>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easier way is the following. We can consider $G$ as the group of $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$: 
$$G=\{ z\in\mathbb{C}: z^n=1\}.$$
Suppose $d$ divides $n$. Consider $z_0$ a generator of $G$. Then take $H=\langle z_0^{n/d}\rangle$. It can be shown that this is a (cyclic) subgroup of order $d$.

Uniqueness: if $H_1\neq H_2$ are cyclic subgroups of order $d$, then the equation $X^d-1=0$ will have more than $d$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$, a contradiction.

Comment: In this argument, we do not have to play too much with gcd and lcm business; simply use of complex numbers.